# How to Pause , Stop recording and resume back and start recording FMS AS

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-media-server

Recording module in Flash AS3, which records live stream to FMS.
want to pause recording or stop rec.
what should I write.
my code It doesn't work.

```
private function handlePause(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    ns.pause();
}
private function handleStop(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    ns.close(); 
}
```

Comment: what is ns in your code? movieclip? sound? netstream? netconnect?

Comment: FMS is Flash media server on which i sending my data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used FMS, but some constructive googling made me come across a post about **"Simple AS3 Recorder"** and that post together with the **"as3LanguageRef for NetStream"** should be able to give you what you need in regards to start/stop publishing a stream.

- http://labs.influxis.com/?p=949
- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html

When it comes to pausing a recording session, there are a lot of issues you have to solve, since you are "**pausing a netstream that is publishing**" it seems like these guys found a way to work around it:
http://www.justskins.com/forums/pausing-a-netstream-while-53312.html

If you look at the labs.influxis-side, there you can find the easiest code sample on how to play/stop a published stream.

Answer (score 0):

According to the AS3 language reference, these are the options available for a NetStream.

pause/resume:

- ns.togglePause();
- ns.pause();
- ns.resume();

stop:

- ns.stop();

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html

Comment: Honestly I haven't used these much myself (just other peoples code I had to modify using them in the past), but I think those methods only apply to a stream that the client is receiving rather than broadcasting.

Answer (score 0):

> Parameters name A string identifying the stream to publish. If you
>   pass false, the stream stops publishing. Use the following syntax:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/ssaslr/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a11aff5ba-7d13SSASLR.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a11afc95e-7fd6SSASLR

```
ns.publish(false);
```

seems this would stop it though I'm not a user of FMS or Red5, in terms of pause I'm not sure.

**Edit**

Ahh It would appear that you can also specify how to start the stream back up, using this also from that doc:

> howToPublish An optional string specifying how to publish the stream.
>   Valid values are "record", "append", "appendWithGap", and "live". The
>   default value is "live". If you omit this parameter or pass "live",
>   live data is published but not recorded. If a file with this name
>   already exists on the remote server, it is deleted.

If you want a more direct answer I would have to see where your initial ns.publish is called.